# Make arrays the same length, append json string

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a Python script that adds to a list:

```py
column = defaultdict(list)

[...]

for line in out.splitlines():
    column[i + 1].append({"row": str(line)})

[...]

f = open(save_dir + 'table_data.json', "w+")
f.write(json.dumps(column))
f.close()
```

This will ultimately generate a JSON file, with a string like below:

```
{ "1":[
      {
         "row":"Product/Descriptian"
      }
   ],
   "2":[
      {
         "row":"Qty/unit"
      },
      {
         "row":"Text"
      }
   ],
   "3":[
      {
         "row":""
      }
   ]}
```

As you can see, `array["2"]` have two values. I am trying to make all arrays the same length. So `array["1"]` and `array["3"]` will ultimately also have two values.

So in order to do this, I figure I have to find the longest array first:

```
longest_array = (max(map(len, column.values())))
```

This should return `2`. Now I want to append an empty `{"row":""}` to the other arrays, to make it the same length:

```
final = ([v + ["{'row'}: ''"] * (longest_array - len(v)) for v in column.values()])
```

Which outputs below JSON string:

```
[
   [
      {
         "row":"Product/Descriptian"
      },
      {
         "row":""
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "row":"Qty/unit"
      },
      {
         "row":"Text"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "row":""
      },
      {
         "row":""
      }
   ]
]
```

This seems to work partially. However, I spot two errors in the newly created JSON string:

1. It seems to add another array around the first array. The JSON string now starts with `[ [ {`
2. It removes the "parent" arrays `"1", "2" and "3"`

Comment: Have you tried changing the dictionary in the beginning, befor the dump? It seems easier then correcting the JSON String

Comment: Not quite sure how I can do that, since the list is created dynamically? I don’t know what array will be the longest beforehand

Comment: Sure directly before the dump you can also call: `longest_array = (max(map(len, column.values())))`
And than edit the dictionary accordingly

Comment: I am calling the `final = ...` before writing to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is in line:

```py
final = ([v + ["{'row'}: ''"] * (longest_array - len(v)) for v in column.values()])
```

which:

- It's a ***list*** comprehension (instead of *dict comprehension*): by iterating on `column.values()`, you lose all the keys, and all the lists corresponding to values have been "packed" in an outer (master) list
- Not sure what you try to achieve by the ***double quotes*** (***"***) in `["{'row'}: ''"]`: that's a list with one **string** element

To solve your problem, turn the above line into:

```
final = {k: v + [{'row': ''}] * (longest_array - len(v)) for k, v in column.items()}
```

and *final* will become the expected dictionary:

> ```
> >>> column
> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1': [{'row': 'Product/Descriptian'}], '2': [{'row': 'Qty/unit'}, {'row': 'Text'}], '3': [{'row': ''}]})
> >>>
> >>> longest_array_len = max((len(v) for v in column.values()))
> >>> longest_array_len
> 2
> >>> final = {k: v + [{'row': ''}] * (longest_array_len - len(v)) for k, v in column.items()}
> >>>
> >>> final
> {'1': [{'row': 'Product/Descriptian'}, {'row': ''}], '2': [{'row': 'Qty/unit'}, {'row': 'Text'}], '3': [{'row': ''}, {'row': ''}]}
> ```